# Mysql recover Memory table data after restart

Tags: php, mysql, heap-memory

There is a table say `data_table` which has lot of `SELECT` queries done with an autocomplete form depending what user types in the text box (`AJAX` and `MYSQL SELECT` on every `keyup`).

To speed up the process I thought to create a `MEMORY` table `data_table_memory` which could have same data as `data_table`. My problem is that a system restart will erase all the data from `data_table_memory` !

How can I recover my `data_table_memory` after a server restart ?

IMO `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` prior every `SELECT` query and dump `data_table` data if the data is missing ! But this process would again add an overload and delay the search results !

Can someone suggest any other better approach ?

Comment: you could run an event to move these and then run a cronjob to backup the database

Answer (score 0):

"If you want to populate a MEMORY table when the MySQL server starts, you can use the --init-file option."

[14.4 The MEMORY (HEAP) Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)